# Website full content not showing

Tags: javascript, html, css

take a look at this link: http://wenggs.com/site7/site5/
It is not showing full page content. Footer content hides and if I refresh for sometimes then it starts showing. Can anyone tell me if there is an error in css/js?

Comment: Some of your css files not rendered correctly.....

Comment: It is not working on just server. It was working fine on localhost

Answer (score 0):

many css error. Please fix it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

check the css class jspContainer,set

```
width:auto;
height:auto;
```

i think there is a css fault

Comment: check whether all files are present

Comment: jspContainer is set by jQuery plugin jScrollPane